# Saving/retrieving video files in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, nsdata

I've been browsing around but couldn't find a solution to my problem. I'm trying to save some video files to my application's directory I do this as follows:

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// the path to write file
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile"];
NSLog(@"%@",appFile);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:appFile forKey:@"videoURL"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
[webData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

My question is, is this the proper way of saving the movie file and if yes how do I convert the NSData to a file that can be played back via MPMoviePlayer?  Thanks for your help.

PS. I really don't want to use the photo library as the app is likely to hold a fair amount of videos.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to save it in the documents of your app, you'll have to use [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

it would probably look like something like that

```
NSString* completeFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",movieName];
NSString* filename = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:completeFileName];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filename contents:yourMovieData attributes:nil];
```

You also might need to use [NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To read the video in your MPMoviePlayer, if think you can make an NSURL like this

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
```

then you give that url to your MPMoviePlayer.

I hope this will help you.